# Can Jenkins send email taking recepients from a checked out file?

Tags: email, repository, jenkins

I'm quite a new to Jenkins and I'm stuck trying to configure Jenkins to send email based on a file from checked out files.

Basically, I'm checking possibility to migrate our own build system scripts to run under Jenkins. One of the existing requirements is storing project maintainers' emails in a txt file in the repository. Out of the box Jenkins couldn't do that, perhaps some plugin can do the trick?

It would be great if somehow Jenkins (maybe through some plugin?) could send emails based on the information from checked out copy of repository.

Any help, information or a direction of search would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe with the [Email Ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) which allows you to configure many many things about email :

- Triggers - Select the conditions that should cause an email notification to be sent.
- Content - Specify the content of each triggered email's subject and body.
- Recipients - Specify who should receive a email when it is triggered.

I didn't find the option to directly take the recipient list from a source file, but you can extend easliy this plugin with Groovy or Jelly scripts.

Comment: I'd taken a brief look at this plugin before but was not sure I can alter its functionality. Your suggestion about the scriptability of the plugin looks promising, I'll look into it.